# My MOSFET does not turn off

Tags: mosfet

[image]

I made a simple circuit following this schematic. The load is several motors. At the gate is 3.3V while the source is GND. The pull-down resistor at the gate goes to the same GND as the source.

When I put 5V at the gate, the drain outputs GND. However, when I remove the 5V, the drain starts outputting 5V.

What could have cause this and how do I fix it?

I've tried:

1. Raising the voltage at the gate to 10V
2. Switching the MOSFET out
3. Also changing and resoldering on a brand new board

Both of them did not work. I have read that I could try lowering the output impedance but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Post a schematic that makes better sense.

Comment: Post a schematic that shows all of the circuit. Before doing that you may want to consider how a good schematic is drawn. The small evidence in the snippet that you show gives an indication that schematic is not currently well drawn.

Comment: What is the supply voltage? If it's 5V, you have not described a problem.

Comment: sorry for that it's my first time posting, here's a slightly simplified version of the full circuit

Comment: You have shown +24 V on the schematic but your post suggests that you are using a +5 V supply. Which is it? What are R2 and R3 supposed to do?

Comment: @Transistor I guess R2/R3 are voltage divider to get a 4.88V gate drive based on the voltage numbers near it.

Comment: Your motor should probably have a freewheeling diode, but that probably isn't the cause of the problem you're seeing. Is pin 2 actually connected to the same ground as your gate drive signal?

Comment: Is this your FET? https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stp80nf70.pdf

Comment: _"The load is several motors"_ - How many motors and what are their specs? Where is your freewheeling diode? _"when I remove the 5V, the drain starts outputting 5V."_ - Exactly how are you measuring this voltage? When you do, are the motors connected?

Comment: pin 2 is indeed connected to the same ground as the gate drive signal.  That is indeed the FET I am using. I have not tested the circuit with the motors attached yet, without them it doesn't even work right yet. I measured the voltage with a multimeter.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you schematic correctly, it should be like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPwFzU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you close the switch, R1 and R2 becomes parallel. This makes \$V_g\$ less than 1V which means the MOSFET can never turn on.

> When I put 5V at the gate, the drain outputs GND. However, when I remove the 5V, the drain starts outputting 5V.

According to the schematic, it shouldn't be. Either your schematic does not match the circuit or there's something wrong with the circuit.

Comment: nah it would seem that my circuit and the schematic matches up. I redid it a few times with the same results and i checked the connections of everything repeatedly. I have heard of people receiving "factory fakes" when they order MOSFETs so I have bought new parts (this time from a legit source) and will try again when they arrive